# How to implement Laravel 5.2 authentication with data (email and password) from an API response?

Tags: javascript, php, api, laravel, authentication

Am aware of this question [Laravel 5.2 Authentication via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847953/laravel-5-2-authentication-via-api) but it does not answer my question at all. 
I'm new to Laravel framework and my question might be absolutely naive, please forgive me.
 From what I understand,  In a typical Laravel 5.2 authentication, a database should be created to contain the registered user details, then when a user attempts to login, his details will be compared to what is available in the database before he is allowed accesses to the app then his details are saved in a session to be used as required on other views. 
 Therefore my question is, How do I do the same authentication when the user's details (password and email) are obtained from an API response? Here is what I've done so far.
**AT FRONT END:**
When the user inputs his details, I used jquery and ajax to send these details to a function in the controller like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:baseUrl+'/getAPI',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        email: $("input#email").val(),
        password: $("input#password").val(),
    },
    success:function(response){
        //redirect to home page
        var response = JSON.parse(response);
        if(response.status == "ok")
          window.location.href = '/home';
        else 
          window.location.href = '/login';
    },
    error: function(response){
        $('body').html("Something went wrong!");
    }
});
```

My routes.php looks like this

```
Route::get('home', 'CharmeController@home');
Route::post('getAPI', "CharmeController@getAPI");

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {});
```

My MyController.php looks like this.

```
function getAPI(Request $req){
  $details = $req->all();
  $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $url = 'url/to/api';
  $response = $client->request('POST', $url,['form_params' => $details])->getBody();
  $data = json_decode($response, true);
  $status =  array_get($data, 'status');
  if($status == 'error')
    return json_encode('{"status":"error"}');
  else if($status == 'ok'){
    $name =  array_get($data, 'name');
    $password=  array_get($data, 'password');

    //I have no idea how to perform authentication 
    //with the $name and $password details from here.

    return json_encode('{"status":"ok"}');
  }
}
```

I'm stuck here, I have no idea how to continue. I don't know how to perform authentication with the details I got from the API. Please I'll appreciate an explanatory answer. As I said earlier, am new to the Laravel framework. 
**NOTE:** My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723888/laravel-5-authenticate-users-through-external-api) but there is no precise answer on it. Thank you in anticipation of your responses.